# Analysing a tree without fixed/static semantics?

Tags: parsing, dynamic, compiler-construction, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to analyze a dynamic language that can have multiple translations, depending upon probabilities. I have a few defined types in my language such as number, vector, etc...

For example, if we were to see the expression 'a+b' then that could be the addition of two numbers or it could be the addition of two vectors.
A number is more likely and so we think the 'best' representation is the sum of two numbers. However it is possible that they are vectors, and so I still want to keep this 'less likely' representation.

If later on I saw 'a/b' then I know that they can't be vectors, as vector division is undefined. So I would throw away the 'vector' representation and the correct one prevails.

I want to do this by analysing an AST. The problem is that due to the many possible combinations of types and operators, we have a combinatorial explosion.

Any ideas on a suitable strategy or pattern that I could use? I'm thinking about a type of visitor for different combinations, that run in parallel to give the best meaning to a structure. Sort of like analyzing a sentance in natural language processing.

I'm using ANTLR's tree walking mechanism for the analysis, so any references specific to that system, or implementing semantics for a dynamic language would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you can find a copy of the "Dragon Book" (Compilers, Principles, Techniques and Tools, by Aho, Sethi & Ullman), read chapter 6 with particular reference to the unification algorithm in 6.7. (My copy is from the 1980s, so the chapter numbers might have changed. But the word "unification" will be the key.)

Comment: Thanks, but the Dragon Book seems too abstract for my liking. I'll look into unification.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is essentially a **type inference** system, from my point of view, which is the automatic deduction of the type of an expression in a programming language. You can start from [the wikipedia page about type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference), and then take some time to understand [the Hindley–Milner algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner).

The AST is just the very beginning of a compiler, so you should try to be accustomed to build a concrete data structure of the AST and write visitors to traverse the tree multiple times. The semantics part only begins after you have constructed the whole AST.

Comment: Thanks. I already have a fully working AST, and have used several different visitors to rewrite certains parts of it. I've implemented static type systems before, just never done any inference stuff.